# Removing Queryset <>tags from being displayed with my query

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to display a query to a template and I am getting the correct data output but it is being displayed with Queryset<>tags, I believe the reason for this is using .all within my template to make the query but I am unable to figure out how I would display the information with out using .all

models.py

```
class SectionMeetingDate(models.Model):
    section_date = models.DateField()
    # time stamps when a cost center is created or updated
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.section_date)

class SectionMeeting(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    section_meeting_date = models.ManyToManyField(SectionMeetingDate, related_name='section_meeting_date')
    # time stamps when a cost center is created or updated
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class CostCenterID(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dept_leader = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    section_leader = models.ManyToManyField(SectionMeeting, related_name='section_leader')
    department_meeting = models.ManyToManyField(DepartmentMeeting, related_name='section_leader')
    # time stamps when a cost center is created or updated
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def cost_center_id(request, pk):
    # provides the name of the section leaders for each cost center ID
    names = CostCenterID.objects.get(id=pk) 
    context = {
        'names':names,
               }
    return render(request, 'DeptSummary/cost_center_id.html', context)
```

cost_center_id.html

```
{% for section_leaders in names.section_leader.all %}

<h5>
    Section Leader --
    <a href="{% url 'section_leader_date' section_leaders.id %}">
        {{ section_leaders }}
    </a>
    -- Total -- {{section_leaders.section_meeting_date.count}}

    -- {{section_leaders.section_meeting_date.all}}
</h5>
   {% endfor %}
```

currently my template is displaying:
Section Leader -- Albin Ortiz -- Total -- 1 -- <QuerySet [<SectionMeetingDate: 2023-05-08>]>

what I want is:
Section Leader -- Albin Ortiz -- Total -- 1 -- 2023-05-08

I have tried rewriting my query a few different ways but am unable to figure out how to display my information without the Queryset tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Enumerate* over the queryset:

```
{% for section_leaders in names.section_leader.all %}<h5>
  Section Leader -- <a href="{% url 'section_leader_date' section_leaders.id %}">{{ section_leaders }}</a>
  -- Total -- {{ section_leaders.section_meeting_date.count }} --
  {% for meeting in section_leaders.section_meeting_date.all %} {{ meeting }} {% endfor %}
</h5>{% endfor %}
```

I would furthermore advice to prefetch the `section_leader`s and their `section_meeting_date`s to prevent *N+1* problems:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def cost_center_id(request, pk):
    # provides the name of the section leaders for each cost center ID
    names = get_object_or_404(
        CostCenterID.objects.prefetch_related(
            'section_leader__section_meeting_date'
        ),
        pk=pk,
    )
    context = {
        'names': names,
    }
    return render(request, 'DeptSummary/cost_center_id.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.